# VisualStudio - how to not forget "Push" after "Commit"

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I'm learning, but I have had a terrible habit of doing a "Commit" in Visual Studio (to BitBucket), and thinking I'm done, without doing the "Push".  I think it's from years of just doing "Check-in" on TFS/SVN or other.

NOTE: This is a Visual Studio question.  I can't even get command line GIT installed (redtape/politics) unless it automatically installed as part of Visual Studio and I haven't been able to find it.

Is there anyway to change the display below to show what's on the GIT/Server instead of local inside of Visual Studio.  My tendency is to see the commit and I think everything is okay.  For now, I have to add an extra manual step to go to BitBucket and confirm the code is there.

[image]

How can I tell that I've done a PUSH or not by looking at that screen or any other panel in Visual Studio? Or alternatively, is there not a "Commit and Push" at the same time button.  Where I work, they don't want us Commiting daily, and because they want the Commit comments to match a ticket on JIRA.

Comment: It you are on your first steps working with git after spending so much time working on a centralized VCS, it's ok.... after a while you will get used to the concept of "I will only push stuff when I _really_ want people to see something"... which leads me to the following point: Do not feel like you need to push every time you commit. You push when there's a reason for it: - people can see what you did - you will create a MR/PR (if working with gitlab/github) - you need to deploy something and need to go through the central repo - other stuff.

Comment: You could open a terminal and `git status` on the project. If you receive a message like `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 8 commits. (use "git push" to publish your local commits)`, you need to push it

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado - if command line git doesn't come with Visual Studio and the Visual Studio command line prompt, I have to go through redtape to get it installed.

Comment: I've never used git for VS. But I believe there has to be a way to run `git status` through the UI. Maybe a right-click menu, or something like that.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I'm pretty sure both VS2017 and VS2019 show incoming/outgoing commits in your branch history view, which I think is what your screenshot is. Also, do you have Git for Windows installed? If yes it comes with Git Bash, and also using Git commands from Windows Command line should both work, but I much prefer Git Bash because of the syntax highlighting and your prompt showing the branch names and status.

Comment: Did you try running git commands from the VS command prompt? I expect that would work too.

Comment: @TTT Git not found in either: "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" & "MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015"

Comment: @NealWalters VS2015! Hmmm...I assume Git is in your path somewhere for VS to find it. But even if you find it... I'd just put in the request and cut through the red tape to get Git for Windows installed (it's free and open source). Once you learn Git you'll likely use the command line many times per day. In VS2017 and 2019 the Git experience is much better than 2015, but you still can only do a small subset of things. For example you can't interactive rebase, which I do all day long. For me not having a command line would be like driving a stick shift but only being able to use first gear.

Comment: Just noticed this: "Where I work, they don't want us Commiting daily..." Can you clarify that? When you're working on *your* machine, "committing" is kind of like "saving" your work. You may wish to save your work 20 times in a day (which means 20 commits) on your machine, and just push out (share) the final version (which may be just 1 or 2 commits after you tidy them up or squash them down). And even after you "share" it, during code review you may want to make more changes and modify your commits (i.e. interactive rebase).

Answer (score 1):

This may be an unpopular opinion, but you just sort of need to get good at command line for Git. Personally, I think GIT works a little better when I work with WSL with Windows, but I had a lot of success with a GIT Pearl Bash console too.
Basic recommendations:

1. Copy the files from your Git Repository to another working directory. Copy the edited files back from your working directory to your Git Repository, and then use the GIT workflow to commit your changes.
2. 'Git Status' and 'Git Log' can be very helpful commands
3. Don't work from master, but hey, I ain't a cop....

Here is a YouTube video that goes over how to use git status and git log.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USjZcfj8yxE

Comment: It is not an _unpopular_ opinion by any means. Nothing beats CLI git.

Comment: I didn't get why you need that first step. I personally have never needed to copy repository to another folder...

Comment: I'm at one of those government places where you can't install anything without the install police doing it (after filling out requests and getting approvals).

Comment: @Leonardo Just a suggestion. I usually only copy over the files I am editing to a 'Working folder', then copy just those files back. When you use 'Git Status' you will see just the files you edited. I like to use a working directory just to simplify things for me, but there are many ways you can organize your work.

Comment: And I went through a whole GIT course on Udemy a few years ago, but of course that doesn't cover Visual Studio, which is where I spend 90% of my time.

Comment: Good Luck Neal!